# CORS - Ajax Headers

Tags: ajax, cross-domain, cors

I am trying to set some headers for a cross domain request.

Http Client : http://localhost:8080
Http Server : http://localhost:8081

Here is my Http Server CORS configuration :

`"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "http://localhost:8080"
"Access-Control-Allow-Methods" : "POST,GET,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS"
"Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : "true"
"Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Accept,Origin,Content-type,MY_HEADER"
"Access-Control-Expose-Headers" : "Accept,Origin,Content-type,MY_HEADER"`

Any query works correctly until I add a custom header to the request. 
When I do, I receive the following error :

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8081/auth. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.`

Here is my ajax code to add a custom header :

```
$.ajax({
beforeSend : function(xhr) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader('MY_HEADER', 'my value');
},

crossDomain : true,

xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
}

method: httpMethod,
url: url,
data: data,
dataType: 'json',
accept: {
    json: 'application/json'
},
async: true,
});
```

When I remove the `beforeSend` everything works correctly.
Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from NancyFx and I am not sure if it has been fixed now.

You can learn more here : https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/1947.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for the browser to prevent X-domain request when a request header is added. 
You should check that your server is still responding with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.